# PageLayout is delayed when record type is changed by workflow

Tags: workflow, page-layout, record-type, quickaction

I have two record type in Account object.

- RecordType1 => default
- RecordType2

When is the status changed from Open to Active. I'm using workflow to change record type to "RecordType2".

When is the status updated by standard action or using quick action then page layout is delayed. 

I can not do any action. I need to wait from 30 second to 1 minute for page layout refreshed

I think it is a issue of Salesforce. How to report it ?

Comment: Are you facing the same behaviour in other orgs?

Comment: I just checked in my dev orgs. It's not happen. How to resolve this issue in this orgs ?